# Objectify Indexed Entity not available for filtering in the google cloud datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have an Objectify Entity with a field declared as shown below

```
@Index
private @Load 
Ref<Course> course;
```

but I cant use this field to search for the entities in the google cloud console because its not available in the drop down  list of available parameters which can be used to filter.
Note: This field was indexed after data had been added in the data store.

what could be the cause of this? do I have to alter the composite indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single-property indexes are created on a per-entity basis when the entity is saved. Unlike multiproperty indexes configured in `datastore-indexes.xml`, simply changing the java file will not have any effect on the stored data.

You will need to resave all relevant entities in order to index this field.

Comment: do I have to save all the record for the particular Entity? or just saving one of them would do?

Comment: You must resave any entity whose index you want to change. The single-property indexes are added/updated on individual entity write.

Comment: you can enforce the indexing instead of running through all the entities , checkout this answer , http://stackoverflow.com/a/34583510/5836034